# Android: NullPointerException when using Extras in Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

Please I get a NullPoiterException when I try to get the extras form the intent.
The error is thrown exactly when I call

```
int posizione2 =Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)));
```

Any help very much appreciated!

```
private void aggiungiImm(View arg1, int arg2) {
    Intent i=newintent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Integer.toString(arg2));
    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);    
}    

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    Uri contactData=null;
    if (requestCode==PICK_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
    contactData=data.getData();                     
    int posizione2 =Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)));
```

EDITED:
No solution so far.
Can it be that the problem is related to the fact that this is an Implicit Intent??

Comment: getStringExtra(String name)

Comment: this will never work until you have not use `setResult` in another Activity from which user coming back to `onActivityResult` Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
int posizione2 =Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)));
```

Try that:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras==null) {
  Log.e( "", "No extras provided" );
  return;
}

String myText = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (myText==null) {
  Log.e( "", "No text provided" );
  return;
}

int posizione2 = Integer.parseInt(myText);
```

Should help you to see what is giving the exception...

By the way, your returned text (if that text is comming as result from the other activity) will be available in the Intent passed to the function. So you should be doing:

```
if (data.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)==null) {
  Log.e( "", "No text provided" );
  return;
}

int posizione2 = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
```

The `getIntent()` method will give you the intent with which the calling activity had been started. No the intent holding the result of the called activity.

If you are getting the `No text provided` message, that means you have not properly returned the result in the activity that computes it.

Comment: See end of the answer: `int posizione2 = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `data.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)`

Comment: `getIntent()` never worked inside `onActivityResult` because data always come back in last parameter `Intent data`